# Run .NET Tests in Production

Tags: .net

I've just added a user management for my code, with a `CurrentEnvironment.IsDevelopment()` switch in the `Startup` class to add a simpler user management for debug purposes (if your name is "Alice", you get all the permission).

Now this works for me on my system for both running the application and tests.

However when the code gets pushed to GitLab, tests will be executed with this line:

> dotnet test -c Release

And now they fail, from what I can gather because now `CurrentEnvironment.IsDevelopment()` returns false. However, if I run the very same command on my local machine, `CurrentEnvironment.IsDevelopment()` is still true, which makes debugging incredible hard.

So my question is: How do I executes my local tests with  `CurrentEnvironment.IsDevelopment()` set to false? And just for my curiosity: why do these commands work differently for the different machines (GitLab is a `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0` docker image, my machine is Win10)?

Comment: It is pretty common to set the environment variable `aspnetcore_environment` to "Development" on your dev environments - I don't think building in release mode changes that. It defaults to production, which you can read more about here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @Jeppe `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is indeed set to "dev" for GitLab, it still builds in  production environment. And that's okay for me, I want to build locally in production, too.

Comment: Do you mean it is literally set to "dev"? It must be "Development", "Staging" or "Production". Can you verify that? launchSettings.json might also set the environment variable.

Comment: @Jeppe Yes, literally set to "dev", which might explain why it's building with the Production environment, even though I don't think it's the default value. Still, the problem is that I don't know how to test in Production locally. It's okay that GitLab builds like that, even if it is a "two wrongs make a right" situation.

Comment: Try running it like this: `set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Production"; dotnet test -c Release` (or `export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Production"; dotnet test -c Release` on Linux)